# Looking for scary short story about a group of mountain climbers

Tags: story-identification, horror

Climber A remained at base camp.  Climbers B, C, D & E carried on to the summit.  Climbers C,D & E returned a few days later to base camp and told Climber A that Climber B died in an avalanche.  Later that night, climber B returned and told Climber A that it was C,D & E who died and A has been talking to ghosts.  Who is telling the truth?

Comment: Apparently, a 2014 Chinese movie, Demon In the Mountain, is loosely based on this online short story.  I have watched the movie but for the life of me, I did not know what is going on.

Comment: The movie never officially claimed it was based on the short story.  Only some reviewers of the movie claims that the movie's plot is similar to a short story but did not say the title of the short story

Comment: I found the Chinese name for it, <相信誰>

Comment: The first one was the story, the second was a review relating the film to the book.

Comment: Thank you. But i have use a translator.  Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### "Who to Believe" (相信誰)

According to [this site](http://www.jaynestars.com/news/ron-ng-and-stephy-tang-in-horror-flick-bleeding-mountain/), *Bleeding Mountain* (possibly the same film as *Demon in the Mountain* is based on this short story:

> Bleeding Mountain is adapted from a short online ghost story, Who to
>   Believe <相信誰>. This popular 140 word short story has been circulating
>   for a long time and it is finally adapted into a thrilling horror
>   movie.

It seems to fit the plot, too:

> Surprisingly, in the middle of the night, Ron covered in blood appears
>   in front of her. Ron reveals that during the first day, there was an
>   avalanche, and everyone was killed except for him.   Who should Stephy
>   believe? Are the mountain climbers humans or ghosts?  Most
>   importantly, is Ron now dead or alive?

From what appears to be [a version of the story](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2052810902), machine-translated:

> Then her boyfriend tells her: the first day of the attack took
>   place on the mountain peak hard!  　　All the other people are dead and only he is
>   still alive. Do you know who to believe?